# how to add multiple images in a cell of WPF Datagrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, cell

I need to add three Images in WPF Datagrid Cell.
Normally i can just add 1 Image per cell.

but i dont know how to do it using DataTemplate.

```
<dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>

                                        </DataTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put it all within a `StackPanel`

```
<dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
         <Image ...>
         <Image ...>
         <Image ...>
      </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Depending on the way you want it displayed, you can set the `Orientation` on the `StackPanel` to either `Vertical` or `Horizontal`.

Comment: Thank alot. so funny. I forgot it at all.